# Azure IoT Device to Cloud send message and get feedback?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

In my project I use Microsoft.Azure.Device library to send message Cloud to Device. I can get feedback information about send status. In ServiceClient object there is a GetFeedbackReceiver method. Everything works perfect.
But I want also check status of sending message from Device to Cloud. In object DeviceClient I don't see any method to receive feedback. 
What is the best solution to check that device has sent a message? Catch exception on sending method or is there better solution?

I saw in sample application to send D2C message in node.js:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/node/device/samples/simple_sample_device.js
that method  client.sendEvent(message, printResultFor('send'))
gives a feedback. Is this functionality missed in c# implementation?

Answer (score 1):

`DeviceClient.SendEvent()` returns an `IAsyncAction`, which represents an asynchronous operation without a result type. Kind of like a `Task`. This means the only thing you can do is `await` the result. You will know if sending the message failed if an exception is thrown. Otherwise it succeeded.